# Continuity of solutions of an ODE with respect to initial conditions: example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I'm reading this notes about the continuity of solutions with respect to initial conditions and parameters: [http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sph/1275/1275notes7-13.pdf](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Esph/1275/1275notes7-13.pdf).

Here, they say:

> Here is another example:
>
> $$\begin{cases}y'=ky^2 \\y(0)=\alpha\end{cases}$$
>
> Using separation of variables we can show that the unique solution is
>
> $$\phi(t,\alpha,k)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha kt}.$$
>
> If $\alpha=0$, then $\phi=0$ on $-\infty<t<\infty.$ **If $\alpha k>0,$ then the solution exists on $(-\infty,1/\alpha k)$.If $\alpha k<0,$ then the solution exists on $(1/\alpha k,\infty)$.**

The last part is the part that I don0t understand. Why the solution if $\alpha k>0$ is defined on  $(-\infty,1/\alpha k)$, and not on $(1/\alpha k,\infty)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k,\alpha$ have the same sign, bad things happen going forward in time: $|y|$ grows faster and faster until finite time blowup. Going backward in time, $y$ just goes to zero and so nothing bad happens.

When they have the opposite sign, everything is reversed.

Another way to see this is just to note that you have a formula for the exact solution in hand. In general the maximal domain of the solution is the largest interval contained in the domain of the *formula* for the solution which contains the initial time (i.e. $0$). This idea that the solution and the formula for the solution can have different domains is often rather subtle for students, so you should think carefully about it.